# Add tools to ionic serve

Tags: npm, ionic2, build-script

I have written many build scripts in package.json using npm, but now that we are looking at Ionic, I want to include additional tools into the internal build process of Ionic.  For instance, we use a started template, and then ionic serve to have the build process run, compile, update the website, then watch for changes.

I want to add the lint process before the build, and then the test execution after, before the page refreshes.  Once the page is refreshed, then other tools for documentation could run (typedoc, angular2-dependency-graph, etc).  I have seen the customization options, but that is not really what I am trying.

Looking into the ionic-app-scripts, it appears that I would have to extend the script by calling the JavaScript functions directly.  Ideally, I just want to add some additional npm lines into the build process.

Comment: How about overriding the default config files with your own? Whether its ngc lint or wepack?

Comment: The config files appear to be just for options in the tools.  In this case, I want to add additional tools into the pipeline.  For instance, add Karma after the Typescript compile to ensure the tests pass, before the webpack is executed.